# jQuery selection vs pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took the example from w3cschool to build an accordion menu. The example is written in pure javascript.
I want to rewrite it in jQuery but it doesn't work.
This is the original:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

and this is my version in jQuery:

```js
$(".accordion").each(function (index) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).next().toggleClass("show");
    });
});
```

The item selected expands but the opened item doesn't close.
Where I'm wrong in my jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a tip, declaring variables like that is nonsensical. I personally define variables as null and them correct them to what I want them to hold seperate from the declaration, but in your case i would just do ``var acc = document.getElementsById('accordion'), i = null;``.

Comment: @JoshCrowe where did you get that idea from? `var i;` is perfectly valid and initializes `i` to `undefined`.

Comment: @JoshCrowe Please don't give wrong tips.

Comment: @Boldewyn I never said it didn't. I said it was nonsensical using ``var`` twice in the same declaration of variables. He doesn't even have to put ``= null`` from my example, ``var acc = "whatever he wanted it to be", i;`` works too.

Comment: @JoshCrowe It is also good to ensure the variable keeps scope, and to organize the code. Write the code clearly and let the minimizer compress it for you.

Comment: @JoshCrowe that's simply a matter of style. Some prefer one `var` and commas, some prefer multiple `var`s for each variable. There's even a ESLint config for each taste. (And the minifier will tastelessly select the shortest representaion anyhow.)

Comment: @Boldewyn Fair enough, shrug it off as a matter of style. I just wanted to note that repeating yourself is not best practice, especially when you aren't required to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove class from other accordions.

```
$(".accordion").click(function () {     
    var self = $(this);

    //get other accordions
    var otherAccordion = $(".accordion").not(self);
    //remove classes
    otherAccordion.removeClass("active");
    otherAccordion.next().removeClass("show");      

    //toggle classes 
    self.toggleClass("active");
    self.next().toggleClass("show");
});
```

And no need of `.each()` for binding events

Comment: Thank you very much! Why the pure javascript is more compact?

Comment: Why I don't need .each() method? $(".accordion") loop to all elements found?

Comment: @robyg72, _Why I don't need .each() method?_ jQuery does it internally for you.

Comment: This solution has an error: the second removeClass have to remove the class show not active.

Answer (score 0):

No need of each(**For loop**)

**First Way**

```js
(function() {

$(".accordion").click(function (index) {
   $(this).next().slideDown();   
   $(this).siblings(".accordion").next().slideUp();   
});

})();
```

```css
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
display: none;
background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

**Second Way**

```js
$(".accordion").click(function (index) {
if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
 $(this).removeClass("active");
 $(this).next().slideUp(); 
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("active");
   $(this).next().slideDown();
  }
  $(this).siblings(".accordion").removeClass("active");
  $(this).siblings(".accordion").next().slideUp();   
 });
```

```css
button.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
border: none;
text-align: left;
outline: none;
font-size: 15px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
display: none;
background-color: white;
}

div.panel.show {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```